# There is a model named `hr.analytic.timesheet` in odoo-8 I can't find it in odoo-10 and odoo-11

Tags: odoo, odoo-8, odoo-10, odoo-11

There is a model named `hr.analytic.timesheet` in odoo-8 I can't find it in odoo-10 and odoo-11 what to do ? Is the model's name changed ?Please Help.Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This model was used to record timesheet activities in the HR modules.
In Odoo 9 it was dropped in favor of using account.analytic.line only.

For reference, compare Odoo8:

https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/8.0/addons/hr_timesheet/hr_timesheet.py

to: https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/9.0/addons/hr_timesheet/hr_timesheet.py

and also:
https://github.com/OCA/OpenUpgrade/blob/9.0/addons/hr_timesheet/migrations/9.0.1.0/openupgrade_analysis_work.txt